# Kotlin:show soft keyboard in webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-softkeyboard

Instead of the classic keyboard, when I click to log in to the webview, I need to open the soft keyboard.
I searched the internet everywhere. tried all the examples and nothing. The standard always opens.
Over the phone, android 11 ,. Made virtual 8 and 9. Same.
How can only be open  a soft keyboard

Comment: "soft keyboard" means the on-screen one, as opposed to a hardware keyboard (with physical buttons). If the user has multiple keyboards installed, which one pops up depends on their system settings

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried those attributes in your XML Parent rootView?

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        >
    </WebView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Web"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val webview = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web)
    webview.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")


}

fun showSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```

I tried, simply, to try.
the same